# How to convert a double in a string, if the string has to meet length requirements?

Tags: c#, .net

Consider the following class.

```
public class DoubleSegment
{
    public int MinLength { get; }
    public int MaxLength { get; }

    public double Value { get; }

    public string GetString(CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Value.ToString(culture); // this is the easy but incorrect way
    }
}
```

As you can see, the length requirements are completely ignored, which is obviously wrong. Now let's say we have `MinLength=4`, `MaxLength=4` and `Value=954`. How do I convert `Value` to `"0954"`?

Please note, that this solution must also work with e.g. `MinLength=4`, `MaxLength=10` and `Value=58723.9843`, which would result in `"58723.9843"` (well at least for `culture == CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`).

Comment: Hmm, just a question: if `MinLength=4` and `MaxLength=6` would `Value=58723.9843` be `"58723."` or `"058723"` ?

Comment: @ConradClark Good question, let's assume, that such a thing cannot happen. The length requirements are defined in the Edifact standard, so I'm assuming that the value range cannot exceed the string length.

Comment: I would not assume such things, especially with floating-point types.

Comment: @CodeCaster Well what choice do I have? Edifact is an 'ancient standard' ;o), so I would raise an exception, in that case.

Comment: `the value range cannot exceed the string length` So why do you need "MaxLength" at all if you aren't going to "crop" the resulting string?

Comment: @ConradClark You're right. Please have a look at my comment before.

Comment: I mean that while the specification can tell otherwise, your data may at some point contain a `123.0999999999999999` value, caused by transport, parsing, calculations, conversion or whatever. Make sure you test for and handle this case, as it _will_ occur in production.

Comment: Hmm, probably the best way is to cut off the string.

Comment: What are the restrictions on the value of Value? Can it be negative, or have its string representation in exponential format (e.g. -1.234567E99).

Comment: @AndrewMorton: Hmm, good. Forgot about that one. No, `Value` cannot contain negative numbers. Exponentional format is also not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Padding to fill the 0 in string.

```
int value = 324;

var paddedValue = value.ToString().PadLeft(4,'0'));
```

Comment: Fits for the first case. And the second?

Comment: Works for me, just replace `4` for `MinLength`.

Comment: @ConradClark That's not the point. What shall happen, if the resulting strings length is > `MaxLength`? What would you do?

Comment: Since you gave the first correct hint with `.PadLeft(...)`, you'll get the mark. My solution differs a bit, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the String.PadLeft method.

```
string x= Value.ToString(culture);
x.PadLeft(MaxLength -x.Length,'0');
```

Comment: @DHN I've updated my answer, since value is a double it requires to stringing before.

Comment: And since `Value` is a `double` it doesn't have a `Length` property... sorry, wouldn't still compile.

Comment: @DHN Nothing stopping you from figuring out the small stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

This is more complicated than it seems at first glance. You need to consider:

- the decimal point is included in the string length
- if the string representation *without decimals* exceeds max length, the input is invalid, but...
- if the string representation only exceeds max length *with decimals*, it can simply be rounded

My solution:

```
    public string GetString(CultureInfo culture) {
        var integral = (int)Math.Truncate(Value);
        var integralLength = integral.ToString().Length;

        if (integralLength > MaxLength) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException();
        }

        var integralWithDecimalSeparatorLength = integralLength + culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator.Length;
        var minimumFixedPointLength = integralWithDecimalSeparatorLength + 1;

        if (minimumFixedPointLength > MaxLength) {
            var intValue = (int)Math.Round(Value);
            return intValue.ToString("D" + MinLength, culture);
        } 

        var precision = MaxLength - integralWithDecimalSeparatorLength;
        return Value.ToString("F" + precision, culture);
    }
```

First of all, if the integral part of the value (not including the decimal) is too long, the value is too large. Otherwise, the precision to use for fixed-point ("F") string formatting is calculated based on available space remaining. If there isn't enough space, a rounded integer is used. The minimum length of fixed-point formatting is the integral, the decimal point, and a single decimal digit (there is always at least one, it won't format to just a trailing decimal point).

With `MinLength=4`, `MaxLength=4`, and `Value=954`, the output is `"0954"`, but with `Value=54`, it is `"54.0"` because there is enough space for `.0`. This would also support cultures where the decimal separator is more than one character long, although I'm not sure if any actually exist.

Some more examples:

`Value=987.654`, `MinLength=4`, `MaxLength=4`: `"0988"`

`Value=987.654`, `MinLength=3`, `MaxLength=4`: `"988"`

`Value=987.654`, `MinLength=4`, `MaxLength=5`: `"987.7"`

`Value=987.654`, `MinLength=4`, `MaxLength=10`: `"987.654000"`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe smething like this?

```
       int min_Length = 4;
       int max_Length = 10;
       dobule Value = 56665.66;
        String  temp = Value.ToString(culture); // this is the easy but incorrect way
        if (temp.Length < min_Length)
        {
            while (temp.Length < min_Length)
            {
                temp = "0" + temp;
            }
        }

      else if (temp.Length > max_Length)
            {
                temp = temp.Substring(0, max_Length);
            }
            return temp;
```

Comment: Hmm, probably a solution. But I'm still trying to decide, what's better. Cut of the string or raise an exception?